# Using an object prop as a key for another object in TS

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

I'm trying to export an object with valid types and create a type based on it. Its working as expected. The problem here is the Option interface that isn't accepting a object key as key name, even if they are strings.

```js
export const SortValues = {
  NEWER: 'NEWER',
  OLDER: 'OLDER',
  NAME_ASC: 'NAME_ASC',
  NAME_DESC: 'NAME_DESC',
}

interface Option<T = string> {
  key: T;
  value: string;
}

type SortValuesType = keyof typeof SortValues;

// type SortValuesType = 'NEWER' | 'OLDER' | 'NAME_ASC' | 'NAME_DESC'; // This also doesn't work.

export const options: Array<Option<SortValuesType>> = [
  { key: SortValues.NEWER, value: 'Mais novos' },
  { key: SortValues.OLDER, value: 'Mais antigos' },
  { key: SortValues.NAME_ASC, value: 'A - Z' },
  { key: SortValues.NAME_DESC, value: 'Z - A' },
];
```

I'm getting the error `"Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"NEWER" | "OLDER" | "NAME_ASC" | "NAME_DESC"'."` on the key prop of options.

Also, it works if I define SortValues as an enum, however it is causing some other problems for me, so I needed to export it as an object.

Here is a snippet
https://codesandbox.io/s/fqide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an `as const` assertion. Even in const definitions, property values will be widened so the type of `NEWER` will be `string` not the string literal type `'NEWER'`. The `as const` will instruct the compiler to keep string literal types

```
export const SortValues = {
  NEWER: 'NEWER',
  OLDER: 'OLDER',
  NAME_ASC: 'NAME_ASC',
  NAME_DESC: 'NAME_DESC',
} as const
```

[PLAY](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=11#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wMrRgNQIYA2ArsKnALxwDeAUHHAHICiA6kwEoBccA5M2+x4AaOnADyAGQAiHbj0kzBI+gwCCAWSYB9VRgDCctZp37hoo9pn7DGy01MiAvnDxkkaGDRoBLZDGBQAGZ4CMDiYDDeKAA8ACoUcOhQvgDmAHzUogDWwACe3LEA3KIAboQk3EmpxY5eMLlgYViw+MSksQ1hlDm5EIFw9Y19cM245aTFNAD0UwOdI9itJKgdjQl8rBw8cAA+vApbu7wWJnrbe3y2WlZnhXAzcLEAFt5khKgQcAAmEKTIPPAAO7QLIAOi8oEgsEQKHQcAgESiaG4qigUDwuWiYkRMVGS3anTSGUoAG1RFQ4D1uHjxqhQfwOEI4GU2nJ1HhXnBkBAShBUNtHMpqJS8tTFrTQQd2EyWRVeOzOXg-N4UnyBUKKVSFi0JSddHoZeM5Ko4ABaOAALXV5JF+W1YzadJON0NrN4FrNcFU1oAusUgA)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks.